# Leetcode Rust 27 Remove Element

Tags: algorithm, rust, data-structures, functional-programming

Here's my solution. Maybe it looks a little complicated and unnecessary. I passed 105/111 tests, so I wanted to find where the bug is in my code.
Here you can direct to the Leetcode page. [Remove Element](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/)

```rust
    pub fn remove_element(nums: &mut Vec<i32>, val: i32) -> i32 {
        let mut temp = Vec::new();
        let len = nums.len();
        for (i, v) in nums.iter().enumerate() {
            if *v == val {
                temp.push(i)
            }
        }
        let new_len = temp.len();
        temp.iter()
            .skip_while(|x| (len - new_len..len).contains(x))
            .zip((len - new_len..len).skip_while(|x| temp.contains(x)))
            .map(|(a, b)| {
                nums[*a] = nums[b];
            })
            .collect::<()>();
        (len - new_len) as i32
    }
```

My idea is to create a vec `temp` which stores the indexs of the elements that equal to the `val`, which is to be deleted.

Then I use functional programming. The brief idea is to set the end of the nums as swap area with length of the `temp.len()`. Then I swap all the values that don't equal to the `value` to the front with the indexs stored in `temp`(undoubtedly we need to omit the indexs that is already in the swap area)

Here is the error testcase:

```
# Testcase:
[4,2,0,2,2,1,4,4,1,4,3,2]

# Answer:
[3,2,0,2,2,1,4,1]

# Expected:
[2,2,0,2,2,1,3,1]
```

Maybe you should test this code in the leetcode yourself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You've changed the order of the original input.

Comment: The order of the original input doesn't matter in this question, the most important is that the `nums[len-new_len:]` doesn't contain the `val`

Comment: You might want to look at [`Vec::swap_remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap_remove). You should be able to just iterate over the indices in reverse and use `swap_remove` on each elem that matches `val`.

Comment: @PitaJ The "purpose" of this particular question is to implement an algorithm, not use library methods to do it in a one-liner. Still I feel like this is a "help me debug my code" question, which probably isn't suitable for SO.

Comment: You need to remove the items backwards. Otherwise you will change the positions of the elements so the indices no longer point to the right place.

Comment: [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=517923d51958e58c5d38a15ef001812f) are two solutions. The second one is yours, but with my suggestion, and then removing unnecessary things and replacing `map` + `collect` with `for_each` to fix the warnings (and make it even shorter).

Comment: @PeterHall fair enough, but here's a simpler version of your first solution, no need for the inner loop: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b9620d1abe09504a717cab1fef250bc1

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks a lot! I found that I should use `filter` instead of the `skip_while`, as `skip_while` will yield all the rest elements as soon as it reaches the first `false`, which is not expected. And your first method passed all tests with high speed and low memory usage, while the second didn't pass all for some logical leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I should use `filter` instead of `skip_while`, that's where the problem is.

```rust
    pub fn remove_element(nums: &mut Vec<i32>, val: i32) -> i32 {
        let mut temp = Vec::new();
        let len = nums.len();
        for (i, v) in nums.iter().enumerate() {
            if *v == val {
                temp.push(i)
            }
        }
        let new_len = temp.len();
        temp.sort_by(|a, b| b.cmp(a));
        temp.iter()
            .skip_while(|x| (len - new_len..len).contains(x))
            .zip((len - new_len..len).filter(|x| !temp.contains(x)))
            .for_each(|(a, b)| {
                println!("{a} : {b}");
                nums[*a] = nums[b]
            });
        (len - new_len) as i32
    }
```